# Extra data specific to usertypes

Tags: django

i have a usertype model with choicefield usertype i.e 1 and usertype i.e. 2
usertype is in one to one relation with usermodel. Now I need to create a specific field for usertype 2 only.

How do I extend user profiles according to user types(role)

```
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
      (1, 'student'),
      (2, 'teacher'),

  )

  user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=140)  
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=140)  
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbpath', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Profile of user: %s' % self.user.username
```

Comment: Okay so what have you tried with views?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two decorators for seperating views with different permission i.e. **Teacher** & **Student**
I used the built-in [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) to create two custom decorators. One to test if the user is a student and the other one to test if the user is a teacher.

**`App/decorators.py`**

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test


def student_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='login'):
    '''
    Decorator for views that checks that the logged in user is a student,
    redirects to the log-in page if necessary.
    '''
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_student,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator


def teacher_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='login'):
    '''
    Decorator for views that checks that the logged in user is a teacher,
    redirects to the log-in page if necessary.
    '''
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_teacher,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

Now in your **`views.py`** you can use the decorator like this"

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .decorators import student_required

@login_required
@student_required  # <-- here!
def some_func(request, pk):


    # body of the view...

    return render(request, 'app/template.html', {})
```